# Potential leak detected for UIBarButtonItem which is autoreleased

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

In the following code xCode's Build & Analyze function detects a

> Potential leak of an object allocated on line 165 and stored into 'addButton'.

addButton is a UIBarButtonItem using the category barItemWithImage (which I read about [here](http://forrst.com/posts/UIBarButtonItem_category_to_easy_add_custom_imag-9Ue)) which returns an autoreleased object. If I don't retain addButtonItem I get an exception on trying to access a released object.

What am I missing here?

```
        UIBarButtonItem *addButton;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        addButton = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedPlus.png"] target:self action:@selector(createStoryModal:)];
    }else {
        addButton = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedPlusiPhone.png"] target:self action:@selector(createStoryModal:)];
    }

    [addButton retain];

    NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             addButton,
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                           target:nil
                                                                           action:nil],
                             nil];

    [toolbarItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];
    self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
```

The category code:

```
    @implementation UIBarButtonItem(MyCategory)

+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barItemWithImage:(UIImage*)image target:(id)target action:(SEL)action{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
}
```

@end

Comment: You say `[addButton retain]` but never release it, as far as I can see. Add a release statement and see if that fixes it. I see that you're releasing `toolbarItems` but by adding it you're increasing its retain count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the static analyzer is right.

remove this:

```
[addButton retain];
```

and this:

```
[toolbarItems makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];
```

and you're also leaking a `UIBarButtonItem`.

`NSArray` retains its elements.

There may be other memory issues elsewhere, but that should remove three of the visible issues/bad forms.

Answer (score 2):

While the item is initially an autoreleased object, when you send it the retain message, you are now an owner of this object, which means you must release it. `addButton` is not being released right now, so that will cause a leak.

Furthermore, you alloc/init a UIBarButtonItem in your toolBarItems array. You don't release this UIBarButtonItem either.

Since the toolbarItems array will increase retainCount of both addButton and the UIBarButton you alloc/init in the array, it is safe to release both after you declared that array. (Or, for clarity, after you set `self.toolbarItems` to be that array.)